# Having a camera and change the background (two activities)

Tags: android

I currently have an activity that allows you to take a photo with the camera and then the image is placed in an ImageView. I also have an activity that changes the background image to another image when a button is clicked. I would like both these activities to run, currently only 1 is working. I understand that you cannot have two activities running, I would like to know what I do. Yes I am new to android and I don't have time to read all the basics with android. I would like to learn by getting help from others, thats the way I learn. Do I merge them onto 1 activity? Do a do something else? Please help :)

Camera Activity:

```
package com.example.triptych4;

import java.io.File;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // label our logs "CameraApp3"
    private static String logtag = "CameraApp3";
    // tells us which camera to take a picture from
    private static int TAKE_PICTURE = 1;
    // empty variable to hold our image Uri once we store it
    private Uri imageUri;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // look for the button we set in the view
        ImageButton cameraButton = (ImageButton)
                findViewById(R.id.button_camera);
        // set a listener on the button
        cameraButton.setOnClickListener(cameraListener);


    }

    // set a new listener
    private OnClickListener cameraListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // open the camera and pass in the current view
            takePhoto(v);
        }
    };

    public void takePhoto(View v) {
        // tell the phone we want to use the camera
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
        // create a new temp file called pic.jpg in the "pictures" storage area of the phone
        File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "pic.jpg");
        // take the return data and store it in the temp file "pic.jpg"
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photo));
        // stor the temp photo uri so we can find it later
        imageUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);
        // start the camera
        startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    // override the original activity result function
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // call the parent
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch(requestCode) {
        // if the requestCode was equal to our camera code (1) then...
        case 1:
            // if the user took a photo and selected the photo to use
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                // get the image uri from earlier
                Uri selectedImage = imageUri;
                // notify any apps of any changes we make
                getContentResolver().notifyChange(selectedImage, null);
                // get the imageView we set in our view earlier
                ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.button_camera);
                // create a content resolver object which will allow us to access the image file at the uri above
                ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
                // create an empty bitmap object
                Bitmap bitmap;
                try {
                    // get the bitmap from the image uri using the content resolver api to get the image
                    bitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr, selectedImage);
                    // set the bitmap to the image view
                    imageButton.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    // notify the user
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, selectedImage.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    // notify the user
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "failed to load", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.e(logtag, e.toString());
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Background switcher Activity:

```
package com.example.triptych4;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MyAndroidAppActivity extends Activity {

    Button button;
    ImageView image;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        addListenerOnButton();

    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChangeImage);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.android3d);


            }


        });

    }



}
```

Comment: You can probably accomplish that with one Activity and make the image changing using AsyncTask that would than send back the control to your main Activity with the new image. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: im very new to android, could you possibly make an example if you have time? I read the page you linked and it didn't really sink in. I learn more from actually seeing an example :)